# Cocoa Single View question

Tags: cocoa

Is there a way to have a single full-screen picture load when the cocoa app is launched?  What I mean by that is a full-screen picture, without the menus and stuff that cocoa automatically attaches to apps.( For example, I want to build an app that when the user clicks it - it brings up a picture of say, a zombie, completely full screen - kind of like the end of that maze game.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not aware of any maze games that feature a zombie at the end (though I imagine it would be a great companion to Plants vs. Zombies), you can achieve your goal by using NSView's built-in full-screen method [-enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) and exit with [-exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html).

To enter full screen at launch, just use the NSApplicationDelegate method [-applicationDidFinishLaunching:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

As for UI arrangement, I'd just open MainMenu.xib in Interface Builder and delete the window, then drag an NSView ("Custom View") or just a NSImageView into the IB document and open it up. Create an outlet to the view in your app delegate / app controller and connect it to the view.

Comment: I think he's talking about a screamer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_is_wrong_with_this_picture%3F#Internet_Prank

Comment: Ugh. I see those things a mile away. :-)